# Cookie theft attack on jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I have an issue on a jhipster:1.10.2 project.

When the client session expired, I have cookie theft attack on refreshing some of my page. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053107/spring-security-invalid-remember-me-token-series-token-mismatch-implies-previ) the reason. When I refresh my page, the first request refresh the remember-me token, invalidate the old one, and send the result to store in the session. But meantime, another request is gone with the old cookie remember-me token.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thx