# How can I config static resource in Spring 4 security using Java Configuration

Tags: spring, security, static-resource

I thought this is easy in xml configuration, but when I am now using java code configuration, I was lost, so can anyone tell me how I can config spring security to allow non-security check for static resource directory?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .csrf().disable()

    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(actuatorEndpoints()).hasRole(backendAdminRole)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(apiEndpoints()).hasRole(frontendUserRole)
    ***//what code can I add here to make static directory/recourse not checked by spring security?***
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().anonymous().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
    ;
}
```

Thank you very much for your kind hlep first

Comment: Don't you mean anything like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455507/how-do-i-define-http-security-none-in-javaconfig/28456037#28456037 ?

Comment: Excellent, but just don't know why that is only for WebSecurity, not in HttpSecurity, so if I want to ignore anything, I have to override WebSecurity signature and put over there, also this means we have to have two configure functions for ignoring and authenticate purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this [How do I define http "security = 'none' in JavaConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455507/how-do-i-define-http-security-none-in-javaconfig/28456037#28456037).

> Excellent, but just don't know why that is only for WebSecurity, not in HttpSecurity, so if I want to ignore anything, I have to override WebSecurity signature and put over there, also this means we have to have two configure functions for ignoring and authenticate purposes?

Not really. There is one more `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, so, I don't see any issues to distribute those responsibilities between different domain objects. From other side `ignore` is more common security function, but `http` is restricted to the HTTP.

From other side your code should be more clear, when you don't pay attention to those `ignored` from the `http` config.

Comment: Can you specify how to use configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) to config ignore? Do you mean we can move ignore to authenticationManagerBuilder?

Comment: No, I mean that it isn't an issue that `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has several methods, which we can override  for our purposes. Please, read their JavaDocs do be sure what and when to do.